# How to analyze the worst case of weighted quick-union method on union-find

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, union-find

Here is exercise 1.5.15 in *Algorithms* 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.

> Show that the number of nodes at each level in the worst-case trees for weighted quick-union are binomial coefficients. Compute the average depth of a node in a worst-case tree with $k = 2^n$ nodes.

Here are my questions:

1) What is the worst-case tree for weighted quick union?

2) How I compute the average depth of a node in this worst-case tree with $2^n$ nodes?

I tried to show through induction that the number of nodes at each level for the worst-case tree in weighted quick-union are binomial coefficients (the first level has $\frac{1!}{0!(1-0)!} = 1$ node). From there I tried to think about how, generally, there are at most $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ nodes at the next level. However, I'm unable to think of reasons as to how this makes sense.

Any help with this question is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please include any work you have done so far.

Comment: That problem is somewhat misleading in the sense that binomial coefficients might be not true when the worst case tree has, for example, 6 nodes. It is only true when the number of nodes is $2^n$.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I think we're supposed to assume that the tree has $2^n$ nodes. If you could provide some assistance in how to devise a proof for a weighted quick-union tree of $2^n$ nodes, then that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use without a proof the following claim that appears in the "Weighted quick-union analysis" of section "1.5 CASE STUDY: UNION-FIND" of the book.

**Claim of (strong) worst case**: the worst case for weighted quick-union happens when the sizes of the trees to be merged by union() are always equal (and a power of 2).

Define tree $W_n$ recursively. $W_0$ is the tree with one node whose component root is itself. $W_{n+1}$ is the tree obtained by combining two $W_n$ using the union procedure. According to the above claim, a worse case is $W_n$ for some $n$. Let $D(T)$ be the average depth of a node in a rooted tree $T$.

(**Structure of $W_n$**) $W_n$ has $2^n$ nodes in total and  $\binom ni$ nodes at level $i$ for $0\le i\le n$. $D(W_n)=n/2$.

Proof. The base case when $n=0$ and $n=1$ is easy.

Suppose it is true when $n=k$. $W_{k+1}$ is the join of two $W_{k}$.
WLOG, let us say one of them is at the left and its root is selected as the root of $W_{k+1}$ during the join. Note that depths of all nodes in the left $W_k$ remains the same after the join while depths of all nodes in the right $W_k$ are increased by 1 after the join. So,
$$ D(W_{k+1})=\frac12 D(W_k) + \frac12 (D(W_k)+1) = \frac12(\frac k2+(\frac k2 +1))= \frac {k+1}2$$
$W_{k+1}$ has one root at level 0 and one node at level $k+1$, which was the unique node at level $k$ of the right $W_k$. The nodes in $W_{k+1}$ at level $i$ come from the nodes in the left $W_k$ at level $i$ and the nodes in the right $W_k$ at level $i-1$, so the number of them is
 $$\binom ki+\binom k{i-1}=\binom {k+1}i,$$
for all $0<i\le k$.
Proof is done.

---

For completeness, let us define a reasonable version of worst cases. As the above, let $D(T)$ be the average depth of a node in a rooted tree $T$. Let $I$ be a quick-find implementation of the union-find data structure, such as (naive) quick-find or weighted quick-find.

**A definition of general worst cases**. Given implementation $I$, the worst case of $I$ with $k$ nodes is a rooted tree $T$ with $k$ nodes such that the average depth of nodes in $T$ is the largest among all trees obtained by $I$ on $k$ nodes.

Let us define $\mathcal W_k$ recursively as follows. $\mathcal W_0$ is the rooted tree with a single node. $\mathcal W_{2^n+m}$ is the tree obtained by combining $\mathcal W_{2^n}$ and $\mathcal W_m$ using the weighted union procedure, for $n\ge0$ and $1\le m\le 2^n$.

(Another version of exercise 1.5.15) Show that any worst case of weighted quick-union is $\mathcal W_{k}$ for some $k$. Compute $D(\mathcal W_{2^n})$.

(Sameness of worst cases) Let $\mathcal A_k$ be the tree obtained by weight quick-union on $k$ nodes using the most accesses. Show that $\mathcal A_k$ is the same as $\mathcal W_k$.

Comment: This is fantastic. I just have 2 questions about the second part of your proof. (1) Would the base case for the number of nodes at each level be when $k=1$ and $i=0$, i.e, ${1 \choose 0}$? (2) Wouldn't the nodes on the left $W_k$ would contribute to the nodes at level $i$ while the nodes on the right $W_k$ would be at level $i+1$ right? Therefore, wouldn't the sum be ${k \choose i} + {k \choose i-1}$? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: (1),  for $\binom ki+\binom k{i-1}=\binom {k+1}i$ to make sense, $i$ should be greater than 0 and less than $k+1$.  Or do you mean I am using $\binom k0=1$ and $\binom kk=1$?  2), it looks like we are writing the same formula, $\binom ki+\binom k{i-1}$, aren't we?

Comment: I think I understand after I read it a second time. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a note for myself in the future, in case anyone else out their ends up getting stumped by this problem. This answer expands off of @Apass.Jack's answer.

To prove that each level has a binomial coefficient, we use induction.
The base case of $n=1$ is ${1 \choose 0}$ is 1. $n$ represents the height of the nodes while the $0$ is just an arbitrary level of the tree.
Now, assume that at each level the number of nodes is ${n \choose i}$ where $0 \le i < n$ for a tree $T_n$. When we combine 2 trees of size $2^n$ (let's call them $T_1$ or $T_2$), then one of them is chosen to point to the root and the other is chosen to become the root. Let's say that the root of $T_1$ is chosen to point to $T_2$. If this is the case, the depth of each nodes increases by 1. That means, in a sense, each node is "pushed" down the tree to the next level below. Now, if, by the inductive hypothesis, we have ${n \choose i}$ nodes at each level of $T_2$. However, for each level $i$ in the $T_1$, the number of nodes at is equivalent to the previous level in $T_1$, $i-1$. Therefore, for each level $i$ in $T_1$ connected to $T_2$, the number of nodes is ${n \choose i-1}$. So, if we count the number of nodes on each level, it's just the sum of the number of nodes at each level of $T_2$ and then the number of nodes at each level of $T_1$ connected to $T_2$. So, the number of nodes is ${n \choose i} + {n \choose i-1} = {n+1 \choose i}$. This fits the form of the inductive hypothesis; therefore it is proven.